# how to delete all contacts in contact list on android mobile programatically

Tags: android

I want to delete all the contact on one button press from my application so can any one nice person can told me how to delete all the contacts from android mobile programmatically on only one button press? answer would be greatly appreciated...

Actually I was surfing from a couple of hours but not got any appropriate answer. That's why I need to post my problem in this nice forum...thanks to such forum....

Comment: @Federico Culloca hi  Federico i think u must have the answer ....  :)

Comment: No, I don't. The fact that I edit your questions or I comment on your submission to ask for clarification doesn't mean I have answers. Sorry.

Comment: Wow, I feel sorry for the victims of whatever prank you're coming up with.

Comment: @Renan may actually not be a prank. I'm actually doing something similar not for joking

Answer (score 28):

It is very simple, This code will remove all your contacts.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = <your app context>.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
```

Done.

Answer (score 5):

Specify [READ_CONTACTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CONTACTS) and [WRITE_CONTACTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_CONTACTS) permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Iterate through each contact and delete each record: [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

[Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)

> Be careful with deleting Contacts! Deleting an aggregate contact
> deletes all constituent raw contacts. The corresponding sync adapters
> will notice the deletions of their respective raw contacts and remove
> them from their back end storage.

With regards to [permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), see Permission groups:

> Caution: Future versions of the Android SDK might move a particular permission from one group to another. Therefore, don't base your app's logic on the structure of these permission groups.
>
> For example, READ_CONTACTS is in the same permission group as WRITE_CONTACTS as of Android 8.1 (API level 27). If your app requests the READ_CONTACTS permission, and then requests the WRITE_CONTACTS permission, don't assume that the system can automatically grant the WRITE_CONTACTS permission.
>
> Note: Your app still needs to explicitly request every permission it needs, even if the user has already granted another permission in the same group. In addition, the grouping of permissions into groups may change in future Android releases. Your code shouldn't have logic that depends on a set of particular permissions being in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will help you delete all contacts, not only from the `contacts` table but also from the `data` and `raw_contacts` tables.

```js
private void deleteAllContacts(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    
        Uri rawUri = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build();
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    
        ops.add( ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).
                withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + ">? "
                        ,new String[]{ "-1" }).build()); //sets deleted flag to 1
    
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(rawUri).
                withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + ">? "
                        ,new String[]{ "-1" }).build()); //erases
    
        try {
            contentResolver.applyBatch( ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops );
        } catch ( RemoteException e) {
            Log.d( "ContactsActivity", "RemoteException --> " + e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( OperationApplicationException e) {
            Log.d( "ContactsActivity", "OperationApplicationException --> " + e );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Enjoy!