# How can I make a button that removes contacts once someone clicks on them, in Android?

Tags: android, contact-list

So I saw two tutorials about removing contacts in Android Studio, but one was an entire project with "selecting features", which I don't have enough space to add in my app, and in the other one I was suppose to create databases and other variables.

My question is if there's any easy solution to make a button that once pressed has the option to select any of the contacts in the list and, upon clicking them, show a message that asks if the person is sure they want to delete it.

Another nice feature would be to make the contacts a different color so the person is sure they're in "delete mode".

What my activity_main looks like:

[image: List]

I also made a class just to remove contacts, but I don't know if it's necessary (this is just the MainActivity):

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<ContactModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MainAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        checkPermission();
    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this
                , Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 100);
        }else{
            getContactList();
        }

        Button add_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

        add_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_Contact.class)));

        Button rem_btn = findViewById(R.id.rem_btn);

        rem_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Remove_Contact.class)));
    }
```

And as you can see, the "Remove Contact" Button is connected to the rem_btn, which in itself is connected to the class "Remove_Contact".

Again, I don't know if it's necessary to make an entire class for it, but I would assume that, because most of the contact list is done, a lot of the code is not necessary.

I'm also learning the various implements in Android Studio, and, as I'm working on this, I also have a limited amount of time to work on this project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that shows you how to delete all contacts in a loop. [how to delete all contacts in contact list on android mobile programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966523/how-to-delete-all-contacts-in-contact-list-on-android-mobile-programatically/7025118)  You just need some of the contacts information to tell which one to delete which you already have from the list.

You may need the `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission.

Comment: Is there a variable specified for when I press a contact; my contacts are divided by sectors, rectangles to be more specific: I wanted my "Remove Contact" button to let me select a contact and then ask if I'm sure I want to delete it. But, for now, just the selection part, because another thing I think would be necessary is a screen color change or something that makes it easier to know when is the button action activated.

Comment: I also don't know what to put in "<your app context>".