# What to replace "app context" with in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-context

Someone recommended me this solution to another question I asked ([How can I make a button that removes contacts once someone clicks on them, in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250502/how-can-i-make-a-button-that-removes-contacts-once-someone-clicks-on-them-in-an/70253188#70253188)), which was this one: [how to delete all contacts in contact list on android mobile programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966523/how-to-delete-all-contacts-in-contact-list-on-android-mobile-programatically/7025118).

In this question, the best answer shows this code:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = <your app context>.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
```

It gives me some errors, since not only do I not know where to put this code (MainActivity or specific class?), I also don't know what to replace `<your app context>` with?

Could someone help me with what app context means, in a simple way preferably?

I don't know if more details are necessary, but if they are, I'll give them!

Comment: If you are in an activity use, no need to use anything for `app context`. If you are somewhere else then passing a `Context` variable should work fine.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, if you're in a fragment, use ```requireContext()```. Activities implement the Context class, so you can just call ```this.contentResolver```

Comment: wouldn't need to do `this.contentResolver` @MikkelT, just `contentResolver`, but yes :)

Comment: Alright, thanks guys, I'll make sure to use this for the best! I'll ask something if and when needed.

Comment: Alright, I'm back with an error: in `String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));`, the `cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY)` part is showing an error that says "Values must be >= 0". Is there a way to fix it?